# Java error code?

Tags: java, import

What does error: `ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type` mean in dr java?

Comment: By "dr java", are you referring to the [tool named DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/)? Don't worry about mentioning that particular tool. Simply mention Java and people will understand what you're talking about. :)

Comment: The OP asked a dupe-like followup question, of sorts, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461699/java-errors-in-dr-java

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to add the line

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

To your source file.  Post the code to be sure.

Comment: okay. I did add that to my code but it gave me a lot of different errors

Comment: Sorry. I am new to java and I really don't know much about it. So I am lost and trying to understand

Comment: Add some more imports for every flavour of this kind of error that you get, then try to reduce the errors down to a small sample program and post a question with the code.  Hopefully people will be able to help!

Comment: My guess?  You've done list.length instead of list.length().   Best to open a new question as comments aren't the place to get answers.

Comment: @Leasha, seeing that you struggle with the most basic java and development concepts (in this and other questions, such as actually posting source code), have you considered that coding is just not for you?

Comment: @Bombe: Never under-estimate someone willing to learn. :) When I started university, I wouldn't have grasped the importing of libraries, especially having come from a PHP background where most everything is automatically in your namespace out-of-the-box.

Comment: Coding is hard but this is my first experience with it. I have never encountered it before. I am willing to learn that is all that matters. Yes, I may not get it right now but with the right tools and my motivation to keep trying and people helping me I will get there. Not everyone in coding stated out great. They had to learn just as I do.

Comment: @Bombe: Fair enough. I just realized that I had to learn many things on my own too.

Comment: Yeah, times change and things change. Asking for help doesn't mean that I can't do it or that I'm not trying. I don't care if you think I can or can't do it. I know that I can if I keep trying. Anyone can do anything if they set their mind to it. My mind is set and you make it sound like a crime if anyone ever has a question about anything. Not everyone learns the same, so think what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It usually means you have forgotten to import the class.
Near the top of you java file, put

`import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: okay. I added that in and got these two errors back: error: the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer> and error: length cannot be resolved or is not a field?

Comment: ArrayList doesn't have a length attribute (its not an array) You may have intend to use size().

Comment: @Leasha take a look at the ArrayList documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html